# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n+5}{n^2}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Determine whether the following converges: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3n+5}{n^2}$$

This is what I did, I just want to check that it is a correct method:

$$3n + 5 > n$$
$$ \therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3n+5}{n^2} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \text{ diverges as it is a harmonic series}$$
Hence by comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3n+5}{n^2}$ also diverges.

Is this a correct method or do I need to add/change stuff?

Comment: It's correct +1. Alternatively, the series is sum of harmonic and p=2 series (convergent) and sum of convergent series and divergent series is .....

Comment: What you have done is fine.

Comment: It's correct though I see no reason to mention the comparison test here. It's clear without that

Comment: Presumably the upper limit of the sum is $\infty$.

Comment: Is the upper bound really $n$?

Comment: @Aryaaaaan I would say it is worth pointing out what test is being used for completeness.

Comment: Of course, this is to be noted that : $ \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2} \ne \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$. Accordingly, you may fix that part in your post.

Comment: @Kyky Yes you're right.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges since it is a sum of a convergent series and a divergent series.